# Cannot return path and flag from procedure

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a procedure that finds if a path exists in the db. I want to return the path if it exists as well as an indicator on whether the path was found. I know that the main part of the procedure works, however the return statement does not:

```
RETURN CASE WHEN count(path) > 0
  THEN {path: path, found: true}
  ELSE {found: false}
END as value
```

When I run the procedure with apoc.cypher.run, if the path is found, it will return correctly. However, if the path is not found, nothing is returned. What should I do to get this to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `apoc.cypher.run()` results in no rows, it will also wipe out the row where the procedure is called.

Within the procedure, you could collect the found paths and return those, that way even if no paths are found it will return an empty list of paths, and you could use the size of the yielded value.list as your check on if paths were found or not.